# Import script src tags for the HTML page in javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML page which has some script imports in the head section something like this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
```

Instead of importing from the unpkg in HTML, I want to import them in a js (Lets say index.js), and import the js file (index.js) in the HTML. Could you please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
function() {
    // Add your script URLs here
    var scripts = [
        "https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js", 
        "https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"
    ];

    var scriptTarget = (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0])
    for (var index = 0; index < scripts.length; index++) {
        var yourScript = document.createElement('script'); 
        yourScript.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        yourScript.async = true;
        yourScript.src = scripts[index];
        scriptTarget.appendChild(yourScript);
    }
  })();
```

Add the URLs of the script files to the `scripts` array to import dynamically.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. I tried your approach, and in the Inspect Elements section, I see the script being added to the HTML. But I get some "Uncaught Error: Script not found" errors in the console. Could you help me with why that would be happening?

Comment: @SaiKrishna Which script is not found?  Each script should show up in the network tab of Chrome if your testing with Chrome.  This will net you see which script failed to load.  Also remember you can't just start using your dynamically added scripts immediately.  You have to wait for them to load.

Comment: This site has a nice implementation for checking when your scripts are loaded.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/async-script-loader-with-callback/